# Rspec to mock my call to external api from my function and return custom response back to the function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mocking, mocha.js, stubbing

So i have written a module which has a function. And now i am trying to test the function.
My question here is that how do i use mocking or stub etc. to test that for a random userid we grab the request to github from the function and return a custom json back to the function.?

Module being tested:

```
require 'json'
require 'httparty'

module util

  GITHUB_URL = 'http://github.com/'

  def get_name(id)
    begin
      response = HTTParty.get("#{GITHUB_URL}#{id}.json")
      data = JSON.parse(response.body)
      return data.first['actor_attributes']['name']
    rescue Exception => e
        return nil
    end
  end
end
```

My Rspec file:

```
# coding: UTF-8
require 'spec_helper'

class DummyClass
end

describe 'GET_NAME' do
  before(:each) do
    @dummy_class = DummyClass.new
    @dummy_class.extend(util)
  end

  context 'for invalid Github ID' do
    it 'return nil' do
      expect(@dummy_class.getName('invalid')).to be_nil
    end
  end

end
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/bblimke/webmock or http://fakeweb.rubyforge.org/

Then you do something like:

```
stub_request( 
  :post, "#{GITHUB_URL}1.json"
).to_return(
  body: { actor_attributes: {name: "Bill"} }.to_json
)
```

I'm a bigger fan of Webmock than Fakeweb (it's got a few more features), but they'll both do for you, and it's pretty easy to switch between them.